# How to get sum from a varchar with commas(,)

Tags: mysql

I Would like to get the total sum from a varchar with commas

This is my sample table, note: price = varchar

```
   +-------+
   | price |
   +-------+
   | 4,500 |
   | 1,500 |
   +-------+
```

My output and query is:

```
Select sum(cast(replace(price, ',', '.') as decimal(18,2))) 
FROM sample.inventory;

   +-------+
   | price |
   +-------+
   |  6.00 |
   +-------+
```

My Expected output should be this:

```
   +-------+
   | price |
   +-------+
   | 6,000 |
   +-------+
```

Comment: Usually you would want to store your numbers as floats and let your application handle the display logic

Comment: yup!, because my given data type in my column is a varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL will automatically cast the string numbers for you.

```
SELECT SUM(replace(price, ',', ''))
FROM sample.inventory
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efefc/2)

However, you shouldn't store the numbers like this...

I would replace all the commas in your price column with an empty string to make it a regular number and then alter your table.

```
ALTER TABLE sample.inventory
    MODIFY price INTEGER
```

#### EDIT:

And if you must have the comma in the result (even though you shouldn't) then just wrap it with [**`FORMAT()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format)

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(replace(price, ',', '')), 0)
FROM sample.inventory
```

[**FORMATTED DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efefc/3)

Comment: @Rahul nice! I posted one myself too :)